# What does "maintain a definition" mean in this passage please?

Tags: meaning

The Census Bureau, the data angency charged with creating statistics on household incomes and their distribution, does not maintain an official definition of middle class status. This is because there is more to the definition than just strictly income; social factors also play a role. Thus, for its definition, the following six indicators are suggested to gauge whether you are middle class.

Comment: '... hold an accurate, succinct, neatly-worded written definition .... 'Thus, for its definition, the following six indicators are **suggested** to gauge whether you are middle class.' shows that it uses a working definition, and that there will be hard-to-decide cases (_the Browns are hard to class accurately_).

Comment: Unless you add more context, and an attributed link, I'll have to close-vote. And even with more of the article, the precise sense of 'maintain' intended here might remain unclear.

Comment: The next passage: While other indicators might arguably be added, a core list of middle class barometers includes: actual income, stock ownership, health insurance, the availability of credit, educational attainment, and the perception of opportunity. Further refinements might include variations by region or time. The goal here is to sketch out a baseline definition.

Comment: In the following section, as said above, the author is "to sketch out a baseline definition".

Comment: I think the prior context would be more helpful! But I can't find a link to this _anywhere_. // The trouble with unlinked/unattributed quotes-or-are-they? is that if they're more specious, the English used might well just be non-standard (though this admittedly sounds more officialese than patois).

Comment: But it is the beginning of the article. There's no preceding part. My young cousin turned to me for help with his homework. I was at loss for an answer.

Comment: So the 'article' cannot be better identified than 'a passage, appearing to be from an official source or textbook etc, on a question paper or equivalent given to my cousin'?  I'd explain this: _Government agencies, educational establishments, scientific groups etc often use 'precising definitions' (see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precising_definition)), more detailed / demanding / precise(!) than those found in general dictionaries. However, the Census Bureau recognises the futility in trying to a put (/ have / insist on) a precise definition on/for 'middle-class'._

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically refer to the verb "maintain", here it is used in the sense of "express" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/maintain

Comment: I'd think that if this was the intended sense, they'd just use 'express': simpler and works fine.  I'm more persuaded towards the 'retain / hold' sense. Yes, these synonyms too would be simpler, but they don't have quite the same sense.

Comment: Well, there is a certain overlap between "express" and "maintain" in terms of partial synonymy although the latter sounds more formal to me. Also, one should also consider the context, which is not clearly specified here. Without any doubts, the "retain-hypothesis" makes equally sense, but then I am wondering whether "an" as an article is appropriate. It should be "the" since the excerpt refers to a definition that has already been established and is well known to the speaker and maybe to the addressees ("official").

Comment: I've tried to find the preceding context, but the article I found says that 'middle[-]class' is _really_ ill-defined (ie has many varied and conflicting definitions) and logically _is_ inherently undefinable in an acceptable way. Precising definitions are always possible (but someone will earn an extra dollar just after you've assessed them, or prices would escalate ...), but would be rejected by other classifiers.

Comment: I meant "context" in the sense of the nature of the source, i.e. register.

Comment: In the sense of "express", the word ”maintain“ usually collocates with "one's innocence" or "maintain that..." is used. "Maintain a definition" is rare.

Comment: ...It is indeed. Though the probably more-to-be-expected 'hold', 'use', 'go with', / 'stick with',  [a definition] would also be quite rare and sound rather off-register. "What definition for 'maintain' are you using?" is idiomatic, but doesn't transfer across too well here. And '...has no official definition for ...' sounds like they're guilty of dereliction of duty. _My sympathies to the poor style-advisor on this one._

Comment: Welcome back to italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

In your passage, *maintain* means *assert* or *declare* (or—more simply—*have*):

[*verb* **maintain** = *verb* **assert**, **claim**; **argue for**](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/maintain)

So:

*The Census Bureau . . . does not declare an official definition of middle class status.* [because there is no way to do that based on income data alone]

Comment: This usage is rare. Can you find a link explaining it or more illustrative sentences? Luckily, I've found one:...D'Ormesson's insistance on the " universal " characteristics of her prose reads problematically as an attempt to maintain a definition of " universal " as a somehow nongendered although singularly masculine term...

Comment: @Allan: *Maintain* meaning *assert* or *declare* is hardly rare; you can find that sense in any dictionary. And I knew what it meant without looking it up (for what that's worth). You can maintain/assert/declare a definition, your innocence, a hypothesis, etc.

Comment: "Maintain your innocence" and "maintain that..." are frequently used; "maintain a definition/hypothesis" is rarely seen in dictionaries and articles. It'll be very helpful if you post links to relevant dictionaries and illustrative sentences.

Comment: @Allan: That's like saying *eat a banana* is common but *eat a kumquat* is rare.

Comment: In my opinion, it's better for an author not to use rare collocations. More importantly, I can't ascertain the meaning of "maintain a definition". The Cambridge definitions of "maintain": 1. continue to have(insist on); 2. express firmly your belief that something is true(assert). Which should I choose?

Comment: @Allan: Based on context, you would choose **2.** *assert*.

Comment: On the contrary, "maintain" means "insist on" in this sentence:...D'Ormesson's insistance on the " universal " characteristics of her prose reads problematically as an attempt to maintain a definition of " universal " as a somehow nongendered although singularly masculine term...? "Insistance on" is notable in it.

Comment: @Allan: I was referring to the context of the original passage. Nevertheless, I don't think that *maintain* in your latest example means *insist on.* Why would the writer say that D'Ormesson's insistence reads as an attempt to insist on a definition?

Answer (score 1):

In the context, it’s basically saying that the Census Bureau don’t publish a formal definition of the term “middle class” that can be applied to their statistical data.

Assuming we’re taking about the United States Census Bureau, they publish definitions of all of their technical terms here:

https://www.census.gov/main/www/glossary.html

> As one of the nation's key statistical agencies, the Census Bureau collects data on many topics vital to people and businesses. The Census Bureau adheres to scientific methods and therefore often uses precise technical terminology that may be unfamiliar to the public. Listed below are some of the major glossaries from our data programs to help people who wish to understand and use our data.

The original quote is claiming that ‘middle class” is not one of those technical terms.

The word “maintain” is probably being used with this definition in mind:

**Maintain**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maintain

> to continue to have; to keep in existence, or not allow to become less

Comment: If you understand it as "publish a formal definition", "to express firmly your belief that something is true" may be a better option among the Cambrdge defintions of the word "maintain".